# Having several custom cursors on one page

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
.custom {
  cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
}
```

I was wondering if it's it possible to have different *custom* cursors for different functionalities. Meaning can I have a custom .pointer cursor and a custom .default pointer for the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may. How you go about it depends on what you're trying to do. If you're using custom cursors, only the last value is required to match one of the default [keyword values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor?v=example#Keyword%20values) available through the web browser. To specify a custom cursor with a custom fallback, just add two custom cursor URLs to the cursor value list and select a default keyword value for the final entry like so:

```
.custom {
  cursor:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Pixel_51_icon_cursor_click_left.svg/120px-Pixel_51_icon_cursor_click_left.svg.png), 
  url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Pixel_51_icon_cursor_click_up.svg/50px-Pixel_51_icon_cursor_click_up.svg.png),
  auto;
}
```

Here's an example of using a custom second cursor value: https://jsfiddle.net/mzuaqy9w/39/

(The custom cursors used in this demo were accessed from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Cursor).)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use multiple custom cursors on one page.

"The cursor property is specified as zero or more  values, separated by commas" via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor?v=example)

If you want to show more than one at a time, you're going to have to write some JavaScript.